# Laravel Validation with checkbox

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

If `use_shipping` is un-checked and user did not enter the value in the `shipping_note` - validation should have passed but it has failed?

```
<input type="hidden" name="use_shipping" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="use_shipping" value="1" {{ old('use_shipping', $delivery->use_shipping) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }}>
```

Text

```
<input type="text" name="shipping_note" value="">
```

In Laravel request class:

```
public function rules()
{

    return [
        'use_shipping'  => 'boolean',
        'shipping_note' => 'required_with:use_shipping',
    ];
}
```

Comment: What error message did it give you? Did it tell you why it failed?

Comment: The error message I get telling me to enter the `shipping_note` when `use_shipping` is not ticked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `required_with` validation states:

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only if any of the other specified fields are present.

Because of your hidden input, the `shipping_note` field will always be present. Since the field is present even when the checkbox is unchecked, the `required_with` validation will always be triggered.

Most likely what you're looking for is the `required_if` validation, which states:

> **required_if:anotherfield,value,...**
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty if the *anotherfield* field is equal to any *value*.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'use_shipping'  => 'boolean',
        'shipping_note' => 'required_if:use_shipping,1',
    ];
}
```

This should cause `shipping_note` to only be required when the value of `use_shipping` is `1`, which should only happen when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately `'required_if:use_shipping,1',` does not work. Still same behaviour as before.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Are you sure? I just tested `Validator::make(['use_shipping' => '0', 'shipping_note' => ''], ['use_shipping' => 'boolean', 'shipping_note' => 'required_if:use_shipping,1'])->passes()`, and it returns `true` (validation passes).

Comment: Sorry, I have tested on wrong page - it is working indeed, thank you :)